# Homogeneous Systems and Symmetric Matrices?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m having trouble showing that given a symmetric matrix $A$, the homogenous system $x’ = Ax$ will be stable (ie it has a fundamental matrix whose entries all remain bounded as $t \rightarrow \infty$).

I know that a symmetric matrix is such that $A = A^T$, but I'm unsure of how to use this information to show the solutions are bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this will be wrong, for example $A = 1$ (a $1\times1$-matrix) is symmetric, but $\exp(tA) = \exp(t)$ is unbounded as $t \to \infty$. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are moreover non-positive, you can use the following:

**Hint**: A symmetric $A$ is diagonalisable, that is, there is an $S \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $S^{-1}AS =: \Lambda$ is diagonal. Now use $\exp(tA) = S\exp{t\Lambda}S^{-1}$